# JinJava on App-Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jinja2, jinjava

Does JinJava work on AppEngine? If so, what do I have to do to set it up?
For instance, where do I put the template files so I can access them without getting an IOException? What gradle dependencies do I need? I am using Android Studio for development. Has someone used JinJava with App-Engine before and don't mind sharing their success?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppEngine IOException file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984269/appengine-ioexception-file-not-found)

Comment: **"This question may already have an answer here:"** Yet you are pointing to a question with no answer. Just because I ask both questions does not make them duplicates.

Comment: The noteworhty fact here is that i refer to a very similar question you asked within 40 minutes. The part "For instance, where do I put the template files so I can access them without getting an IOException?" is essentially the content of your other question. Other valid flags for this post are "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking". To get the best answers you should be more specific. If you wish to ask whether it is generally possible to use jinjava in appengine, you may do so if it's not a duplicate. It's best not to mix topics as this makes answers usually worse and unspecfic.